How do I adjust an entire surface to its merged vertices?
I would like to adapt the upper surface to the ‘columns’ at the front and back so that the surface is bevelled. To do this, I have merged the edge vertices with the topmost vertices of the ‘columns’ but then the inner part of the surface remains flat. How can I adjust this?


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

You can select a correct point, press N to see its properties.
Among the tabs in the properties, you can see the X, Y, Z coordinates of the point.
Copy the z, then select the remaining points and paste that Z.

Alternatively set the pivot point option to "active", select a row of points with shift, then select lastly the correct point. (It will have a different selection color).

Scale, Z, 0


Third alternative, from the side view (click the X axis top right), turn on snapping to vertices. Select the target points and grab them Z to snap to the correct point.

Thank you for the instructions!!
